# Winforms: How to Bind a List to multiple DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to bind a List to multiple DataGridViews such that manipulation through one of the gridviews would be propogated to all other gridviews.

```
List<Domain> data;
```

1st approach:

```
BindingList<Domain> list = new ..;
data.ForEach( d => { list .Add(d); } );    

grid1.DataSource = list;
grid2.DataSource = list;
```

This didn't work.  The grids share properties other than the data.

2nd approach:

```
BindingList<Domain> list1 = new ..;
BindingList<Domain> list2 = new ..;

data.ForEach( d => { list1.Add(d); list2.Add(d); } );    

grid1.DataSource = list1;
grid2.DataSource = list2;
```

This approach works for updates.  However, adds and deletes weren't propograted.

3rd approach:

```
BindingList<Domain> list = new ..;
data.ForEach( d => { list .Add(d); } );    

BindingSource ds1 = new BindingSource();
BindingSource ds2 = new BindingSource();
ds1.DataSource = list;
ds2.DataSource = list;

grid1.DataSource = ds1;
grid2.DataSource = ds2;
```

This propogates adds and deletes, however, when a new row is added to 1 view, but not yet commited, an empty row is displayed in all other grids.  Seems like a new record is inserted into the List before the editing completes.

How can I properly bind multiple datagridviews to one List?  (This is extremely easy in Flex.)  I'd appreciate any reference to the relevant section in MDSN.

Comment: I think you should be able to use one `BindingSource` for all grids, but I must admit that I'm a bit rusty in this area.

Comment: Using one BindingSource works.  However, the rendering of adding a new row is not inconsistent across grids.

Comment: You mean "not consistent"? You probably refer to a double empty row in grids that are not edited when a row is added in one grid? If so, yes, that's ugly, but I'm not sure what to do about it in a decent way.

Comment: Yes :) that is what i meant to say.

Comment: @GertArnold: There's another problem that I face.  When I change list to something else, the grids don't update accordingly.  I need to catch an event that signals the update, and assign the DataSource of the BindingSouce again.  Have you experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little test app, just to make sure that sharing a binding source was possible the way I remembered. You can find it [here](http://www.filedropper.com/sharedbindingsource) (for at least 30 days).

What I found that propbably caused your problem is that all your grids probably have adding/deleting rows enabled. A new row in grid1 is displayed as a new row in grid2, but grid2 (quite unnecessarily) displays a template row below that.

I made a little main window with a read-only grid on a binding source and an edit dialog with an editable grid on the same binding source. The binding source is the only wiring between the two, no event handling to signal updates, no reassigning of datasources. Everything is synced perfectly, even the current row (because of the `CurrencyManager`). A new row in the dialog only shows as one empty row in the 'main' window.

Hope this helps, and is not over-simplified.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep add and delete enabled though.  Thanks.